# Docker swarm for active-standby service

Tags: docker-swarm

Is it possible to use docker swarm for an application which is having active and standby instances (for example: PostgresDB in active and standby)

Currently we have bare metal solution where we run active instance and standby instance on separate hosts.

If swarm is used, then it is creating cluster and doing load balancing.
We are not looking for load balancing.

Is it necessary to have tasks run independently of each other on worker nodes in a swarm cluster?

Because of active-standby instances, application already has the heartbeat in place and swarm is also actively monitoring the workers in the cluster.

Is it possible to disable load-balancing in the swarm?

Thanks and regards,
Sheetal

Comment: You have load balancing only when scaling one service multiple times. When deploying two different service (one active and one standby), there is no load balancing between those services, but the can reach each other when they are part of the same docker network

Answer (score 0):

You would make two services in Swarm, one for active, one for standby. Each service would have one replica and you would connect both to the same docker network :)